# Matlab- Fix fmincon issues with Bayesian updating

Tags: matlab, optimization, bayesian

I want to run bivariate normal Bayesian updating in Matlab using fmincon.

Here are my equations for the posterior mean and precision:

```
%Calc posterior Precision
 PostPrecision                = (inv(PriorPrecision(:,:,t))) + (inv(Covariance));
 
%Calc posterior mean
 PosteriorMeanPrime_t(:,t+1)  =  (PostPrecision) \ ( ((PriorPrecision(:,:,t)) \ 
   PosteriorMeanPrime_t(:,t)) + ((Covariance) \ Signal(:,t)) );
```

I have noticed that matlab will use the prior precision and covariance to "learn" as fast as possible by moving them in opposite directions. Are there any ways I can combat this?